# infiniteProgress component issue in postForm() - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have kept all my connections in postForm(). I did it since one may click the button twice or more if I keep the beforeForm() but the problem is that here the infiniteProgress component get disposed before all the components of the form arrive. It results in blank white screen for a moment. If the network is slow, it takes more time. How can I make it more convenient?

```
public class GroupConnection {
ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> response;

void groupConnection() {
    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
            Map<String,Object> parsedData = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            response = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) parsedData.get("root");
        }

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
            super.postResponse(); 
        }
    };
    AllUrl allUrl = new AllUrl();
    connectionRequest.setUrl(allUrl.groupsUrl);
    connectionRequest.setPost(false);
    connectionRequest.setTimeout(8000);
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    connectionRequest.setDisposeOnCompletion(d);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);
 }
}
```

void postForm(Form f) method:

```
    GroupConnection gc = new GroupConnection();
    gc.groupConnection();
    if (gc.response != null) {
        wrapContainer = new Container();
        for (Map<String, Object> element : gc.response) {
            String tableName = (String) element.get("name");
            String inaugurationDate = (String) element.get("inaugurationdate");
            String areaCode = (String) element.get("areacode");
            String clubAbbr = (String) element.get("clubabbrname");
            String charterDate = (String) element.get("clubcharterdate");

            Container tableNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea tableNameData = new TextArea(tableName);
            tableNameDataContainer.add(tableNameData);

            Container inaugurationDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea inaugurationDateData = new TextArea(inaugurationDate);
            inaugurationDateDataContainer.add(inaugurationDateData);

            Container areaCodeDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea areaCodeData = new TextArea(areaCode);
            tableDataMeetingTextArea(areaCodeData, izz, areaCodeDataContainer);
            areaCodeDataContainer.add(areaCodeData);

            Container clubAbbrNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea clubAbbrNameData = new TextArea(clubAbbr);
            clubAbbrNameDataContainer.add(clubAbbrNameData);

            Container clubCharterDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea clubCharterDateData = new TextArea(charterDate);
            clubCharterDateDataContainer.add(clubCharterDateData);

            TableLayout tl1 = new TableLayout(1, 5);
            containerTableDataGroup = new Container(tl1);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), tableNameDataContainer);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), inaugurationDateDataContainer);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(15), areaCodeDataContainer);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(15), clubAbbrNameDataContainer);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), clubCharterDateDataContainer);

            wrapContainer.add(containerTableDataGroup);
        }
        f.add(wrapContainer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code to be event driven, when the response has arrived refresh the data on the Form, try the below modifications to your code:

```
public class GroupConnection {
ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> response;

void groupConnection(ActionListener callback) {
    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
            Map<String,Object> parsedData = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            response = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) parsedData.get("root");
            //the reponse has arrived we need to inform the UI that the data can is ready to be displayed on screen
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
              callback.actionPerformed(null);

             }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
            super.postResponse(); 
        }
    };
    AllUrl allUrl = new AllUrl();
    connectionRequest.setUrl(allUrl.groupsUrl);
    connectionRequest.setPost(false);
    connectionRequest.setTimeout(8000);
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    connectionRequest.setDisposeOnCompletion(d);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);
 }
}
```

void postForm(final Form f) method:

```
GroupConnection gc = new GroupConnection();
    gc.groupConnection(f, new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        wrapContainer = new Container();
        for (Map<String, Object> element : gc.response) {
            String tableName = (String) element.get("name");
            String inaugurationDate = (String) element.get("inaugurationdate");
            String areaCode = (String) element.get("areacode");
            String clubAbbr = (String) element.get("clubabbrname");
            String charterDate = (String) element.get("clubcharterdate");

            Container tableNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea tableNameData = new TextArea(tableName);
            tableNameDataContainer.add(tableNameData);

            Container inaugurationDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea inaugurationDateData = new TextArea(inaugurationDate);
            inaugurationDateDataContainer.add(inaugurationDateData);

            Container areaCodeDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea areaCodeData = new TextArea(areaCode);
            tableDataMeetingTextArea(areaCodeData, izz, areaCodeDataContainer);
            areaCodeDataContainer.add(areaCodeData);

            Container clubAbbrNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea clubAbbrNameData = new TextArea(clubAbbr);
            clubAbbrNameDataContainer.add(clubAbbrNameData);

            Container clubCharterDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
            TextArea clubCharterDateData = new TextArea(charterDate);
            clubCharterDateDataContainer.add(clubCharterDateData);

            TableLayout tl1 = new TableLayout(1, 5);
            containerTableDataGroup = new Container(tl1);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), tableNameDataContainer);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), inaugurationDateDataContainer);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(15), areaCodeDataContainer);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(15), clubAbbrNameDataContainer);
            containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), clubCharterDateDataContainer);

            wrapContainer.add(containerTableDataGroup);
        }
        f.add(wrapContainer);
        f.revalidate();
     }
    });
```

Comment: No data are displayed if I use addToQueue instead of addToQueueAndWait. I tried it in other connections as well but  it gives dialog box saying check your network or blank form .

Comment: I assume you are displaying the data from the response somehow, although from the above code it's not clear how. you need to add the items to the screen after the response has returned and then revalidate the Form

Comment: I have replaced all the code above. I think I have done all that you have told but the data is not displayed.

Comment: Ok, it is clear from your code that the response will be null, so you are not getting into the loop that adds the elements. This happens because the call to groupConnection() will return before network response. you need to  add all the components to the Form when the response has returned